# How to run tests in a django view without affecting the database

Tags: python, django, testing, command

I am trying to run the functional tests (using `Selenium` in python/django) directly from the django views by using `management.call_command`, in order to allow the user to run the test from the web site. The django view is something like:

```py
class MyView():
    def get(self):
        output = call_command('test', 'folder.tests.MyTest')
        # doing ./manage.py test folder.tests.MyTest
        test_result = 'Test result: ' + output
        return something_http_with_test_result
```

What is the best way to do this in order to do not affect the current user data? MyTest is going to create a lot of object in the database but the user must not see them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to run it properly is to use os.system :

```
import os
dir = 'your_absolute_path_to_project'
class MyView:
    def some_func_called():
        os.system(dir + '/manage.py test >' + dir + '/log.txt')
```

The project and firefox have to have the same owner and results will be in log.txt.